# ListView Image Click changes other images in the list when scrolled

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView which has an image and a text in the relative layout and two texts in the linear layout.. i have set the image to change to text when its clicked in the ListView.. but the problem is when the list view is scrolled the other images also changes to text view..

i read in other posts that its wrong to `setOnClickListener` on a GetView, we can use `setOnItemClickListener` instead, but i dont know how to implement it?
please help..

below is my Adapter class

```
public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word>  {

/** Resource ID for the background color for this list of words */
private int mColorResourceId;

/**
 * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
 *
 * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
 * @param words is the list of {@link Word}s to be displayed.
 * @param colorResourceId is the resource ID for the background color for this list of words
 */
public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words, int colorResourceId) {
    super(context, 0, words);
    mColorResourceId = colorResourceId;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

    }

    // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
    Word currentWord = getItem(position);

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID miwok_text_view.
    TextView miwokTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view);
    // Get the Miwok translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the Miwok TextView.
    miwokTextView.setText(currentWord.getMiwokTranslationId());

    // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID default_text_view.
    TextView defaultTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.default_text_view);
    // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
    // the default TextView.
    defaultTextView.setText(currentWord.getDefaultTranslationId());

   final TextView onClickTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.miwok_text_view_on_click);

    onClickTextView.setText((currentWord.getTextOnClickId()));

    // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
    if (currentWord.hasImage()) {
        // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
        imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
        // Make sure the view is visible
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
        imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

   // Set the theme color for the list item
    View textContainer = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.text_container);
    // Find the color that the resource ID maps to
    int color = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), mColorResourceId);
    // Set the background color of the text container View
    textContainer.setBackgroundColor(color);

    // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
    // the ListView.

    // ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    imageView.setTag(new Integer(position));
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

        Boolean flag =false;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

               // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ImageView clicked for the row = "+view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             if(flag){

                 imageView.setAlpha(255);
                 onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                 flag = false;
             }else{
                 imageView.setAlpha(0);
                 onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 flag =true;
                }

            }

    });

    return listItemView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try to change this :

```
imageView.setTag(new Integer(position));
imageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {

    Boolean flag =false;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

           // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ImageView clicked for the row = "+view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         if(flag){

             imageView.setAlpha(255);
             onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
             flag = false;
         }else{
             imageView.setAlpha(0);
             onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             flag =true;
            }

        }

});
```

> to:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(currentWord.isFlag){
                currentWord.isFlag = false;
            }else{
                currentWord.isFlag = true;
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });

    if(currentWord.isFlag)
    {

        imageView.setAlpha(0);
        onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        imageView.setAlpha(255);
        onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

create an isFlag variable in your Word class
`public boolean isFlag = false;`

and whenever you are initializing your list of  Word type then set the value of setFlag(false);

and this one is happening with you because listview getting refresh items always during scrolling , so you have to use flag also in your list

Comment: i am getting error in the line `currentWord.setFlag(false);`  _cannot resolve method setFlag(boolean)_

Comment: in my Word class i have created a isFlag parameter like this.... `public boolean isFlag() { return false; }`  but iam getting the error in the line `currentWord.setFlag(false);` ... _cannot resolve method setFlag(boolean) _    @krish singh

Comment: @kirsh singh ... your suggestion worked for me just one change i created an `isFlag` boolean variable in my word class ... edited your answer and marked as solved... thanks...

Comment: and dear @amit "cannot resolve method setFlag(boolean)" because you not create getter setter in Word class , you are using the variable directly

Comment: can you give me an idea or a reference on how to create getter setter... is using the variable directly the correct way?   @krish

Comment: yes ,but if you get your answer please mark this answer as correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173194/discussion-between-krish-singh-and-amit).

Answer (score 1):

Since `View` gets reused in `ListView`. After clicking an item, the image in the view item is changed to text, when the same view item is reused as you scroll down, it retains the old state. That's why you see other images also changed to text.

So in order to solve this, create a variable in your `Word` class, which determines in what state the view item is in (image or text). Let's call it `isImage` which is a boolean

Then in `getView` method, based on its current value, initialize your view

```
if(currentWord.isImage){
    imageView.setAlpha(255);
    onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else{
    imageView.setAlpha(0);
    onClickTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
// add a tag to determine the position of the view, when the view is clicked.
imageView.setTag(position)
```

and in imageView click listener

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Toast.makeText(getContext(), "ImageView clicked for the row = "+view.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int position = (int) view.getTag()
    Word word = getItem(position)
        // using the new variable, do the required UI changes
        if(word.isImage){
             currentWord.isImage = false;
               }else{
                 word.isImage = true;
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

also i have declared the isImage variable in the Word class as follows :

```
    public boolean isImage = true;
```

Comment: i am getting an error in the line `Word word = getItem(word)`  _variable word might not have been initialized_

Comment: sorry it should be `getItem(position)`, I have edited the answer

Comment: getting a warning on this line `Word word = getItem(position);` ... _variable word is never used_ ... .@Rick

Comment: It's not a complete code, I have just given the direction. Based on the 'isImage' variable you might have created. Set the variable to false and make the text visible and image alpha to zero in the listener.